# psql select * from user returns sytem user instead of table content

Tags: postgresql

I've a table named user ( gitea db).

when I try to

```
select * from user;
```

I'll get the currently active user instead of the table content.
As I could read, that's normal behavior cause defined like this by psql.

But how can I select the content of my gitea.user table ?
Even quoting "user" did not help.

Comment: is your `user` table in a schema called `gitea` or `public`. try `select * from gitea.user` or `select * from public.user`. a better idea would be to rename the table to `users` so that the name doesn't collide

Comment: `select * from "user"` **will** work.

Comment: It was not my decision to name the table like this...  public.user does the trick - thanks @HaleemurAli select * from "user" does **not work**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is a [reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), so it is a bad idea to use it.

You can use the fully qualified name to refer to your table:

```
select * from gitea.user;
```